# read a UserDefault value when the app starts

Tags: swift, userdefaults

UserDefault doesn't work, when I change the color of the app, then I close it and reopen it I don't see the changes.

My intent is to create the preferences that the user sets on the app.

I also tried putting the code inside SceneDelegate.swift but it doesn't work there either.

**UserDefaultManager**

```
    import Foundation

class UserDefaultManager {

    static let sharedUserDefault = UserDefaultManager()
    
    var darkmode = Bool()
    
    let keyDarkmode = "UserDefaultDarkmode"

    let userDef = UserDefaults.standard
    
}
```

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var theme: UISwitch!
    
    let shared = UserDefaultManager.sharedUserDefault
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // theme.isOn = false
        theme.setOn(false, animated: false)

        if shared.userDef.object(forKey: shared.keyDarkmode) != nil {
            
          shared.darkmode = shared.userDef.object(forKey: shared.keyDarkmode) as? Bool ?? Bool()
            
            if shared.darkmode == true {
                overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
            } else {
                overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
            }
            
            shared.userDef.synchronize()
            
        }
        
    }

    
    @IBAction func themeSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        
        if sender .isOn {
            overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
            shared.darkmode = true
            shared.userDef.set(shared.darkmode, forKey: shared.keyDarkmode)
            
            shared.userDef.synchronize()
        } else {
            overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
            shared.darkmode = false
            shared.userDef.set(shared.darkmode, forKey: shared.keyDarkmode)
            
            shared.userDef.synchronize()
        }
        
    }    
   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set the switch `theme` always to `false` instead of the value in `UserDefaults`.

The shared class is not needed. This code is sufficient, and `UserDefaults` provides `bool(forKey` which returns `false` if the key is missing. If you need `true` as default value `register` the key-value pair.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let keyDarkmode = "darkMode"

    @IBOutlet weak var theme: UISwitch!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let isDarkMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: keyDarkmode)
        theme.setOn(isDarkMode, animated: false)
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = isDarkMode ? .dark : .light
    }

    
    @IBAction func themeSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = sender.isOn ? .dark : .light
        UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn,  forKey: keyDarkmode)
    }
}
```

Side note: Calling `synchronize` is not needed either.